# C# API for XML structure comparison

Tags: c#, .net, xml, api

is there a way to programmatically compare structures of 2 XML files, but not their values?

More concretely, if you have 2 xml files:

```
<car>
<numberofwheels>4</numberofwheels>
<carcolor color="red" dateofpainting="2015-10-10" />
</car>
```

and

```
<car>
<numberofwheels>7</numberofwheels>
<carcolor color="blue" />
</car>
```

it would only notice that attribute `dateofpainting` is missing, but not the change of values (`numberofwheels` and `color`). I also don't care about blanks, newlines, attribute order, etc...

There is an XML Diff and Patch Tool from Microsoft, but as far as I can see, it also checks xml values and you cannot set it up to ignore them.

Comment: Would it be an idea to create a xml-schema from one and then checking the other against the schema? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255829.aspx

Comment: Yes, that solves my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any one of the structure is predefined,then you can use the XML schema do find the mismatch. If not then you have to traverse the document node by node using XMLDocument/XMLReader class and you can get the difference list.